# Should I switch to Rails 3 now?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

According to their blog (http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2010/7/26/rails-3-0-release-candidate), the release candidate for Rails 3.0 is out now, and the formal version will be coming in 'a few weeks'. I've been planning to rebuild my application using MongoDB anyway, should I go ahead with Rails 3.0.0.rc right now or wait for the formal version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Make a `rails3` branch in Git and get that working in development/test on Rails 3 RC. If it's working, feel free to rebase into `master` and deploy to production. Or you can wait until the final release is dropped to rebase into `master` and deploy to production.